# append a string while publishing a package in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-publish

I am running `npm publish` to publish the packages to my source repositories.It picks the version from package.json.  Is there a way while it is publishing the versions , I can append `-SNAPSHOT` at the end of the artifact? For example `myartifact-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT` where `1.0.0` is the version specified in Artifact.

PS: If possible , I dont want to install extra packages like `node-snapshot`.

Comment: update the version in your `package.json`

Comment: I dont want to touch the package.json. I am looking for some way I can either write a one liner `script` in my package.json file.